# Why am I receiving a "no scatter mode specified" error message when making a graph with Plotly in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly

I'm receiving the following error when running my code:

```
plot_ly(data, x = ~RighttoWork_NonRtw, 
              y = ~market_value_level_unfunded_liability, 
              text = ~paste("State: ", state,
                            "Market Value Level Unfunded Liability", market_value_level_unfunded_liability),  
              color = ~market_value_level_unfunded_liability,  
              size = ~market_value_level_unfunded_liability, 
              type = "scatter")
```

> No scatter mode specifed:   Setting the mode to markers   Read more
>   about this attribute -> https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter-mode
>   Error: `size`/`width` values must be numeric .

Why is this the case?

I'm trying to get a series of plot points with different sized points based on the unfunded liability variable figures. Unfortunately, I keep getting this error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to answer without a reproducible example. First off you can specify the `mode`. Then you could try specifying the markers. Here I used your code for an example on `mtcars` dataset. The size of the markers is scaled by 3 here because some times the `size` argument of plotly can't make sense of certain values.

This aside, your error is due to the fact that `market_value_level_unfunded_liability`, your y variable, seems not to be numeric. You should convert it to numeric in a sensible way (use `as.numeric(as.character())` if factor with numeric levels).

```
library(plotly)
data <- mtcars

plot_ly(data, x = ~mpg, 
        y = ~qsec, 
        text = ~paste("State: ", carb,
                      "Market Value Level Unfunded Liability", qsec),  
        color = ~qsec,  
        size = ~qsec,
        type   = 'scatter', 
        mode   = 'markers',
        marker = list(size = ~qsec*3)
        )
```

[image]

Comment: adding type   = 'scatter', mode   = 'markers' only helped me.